# Spring session issue : Session is not reflecting immedietely

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have implemented pages like using Spring framework as follows:

Login.jsp -> Gets the credentials
Welcome.jsp -> I am taking the login name and planning to display as part of the header

Welcome.jsp:

```
<!-- Basic tags and all-->
<div content="header">
<jsp:include>header.jsp</jsp:include>
```

.....

```
header.jsp:
${loginName}

WelcomeController:
@Controller
@requestmapping("/welcome")
public method(){ 
session.getSession.setAttribute("user",loginName);
}
```

This is like a sample code. Executing succesffully. Here the problem is when welcome is page is displayed it's not showing the loginname in the header. Again if I do refresh it starts showing.

I mean from the next cycle. Its not showing at the fist time when I am redirecting to the welcome page in the header. Can you please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following and see.

```
@Controller
@requestmapping("/welcome")
public method(){ 
    session.getSession.setAttribute("loginName",loginName);
}
```

Comment: thanks @shazin for your reply.  Previously i used the same but didnt mention in the code properly.  I apapologize for that.  The problem is at the very first time the loginusername is not reflected in the header.  Its giving null.  If i refresh again i am able to see login user name in the header.  I want to solve out this issue.